# Need to prevent ssh remote server redirect to local file

Tags: ssh

Our sysadmin wants to move off of Linux because of this redirect, any way to prevent it - via some type of SSH config option, firewall rules etc?

ssh myuser 192.168.2.100 'cat confidential.txt' > local_copy.txt

Comment: Yes they will have read access. The concern is moving data easily off of the server. The sysadmin claims that on Windows even the clipboard can be restricted.

Comment: To further clarify, if I can prevent this redirect, I can likely prevent the sysadmin moving the server from 'SSH on linux' to 'RDP on Windows' .

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "prevent ssh from redirecting" since it is NOT ssh but the OS does the IO redirection. All that SSH does is to print its output to stdout, which is redirected to a local file.

And, I do want to say that your sysadm is .... It doesn't make sense to ban the redirection even we can because there are plenty of terminal emulators which are capable of 'capature screen log'.

Comment: I tried the sshd_config option AllowGroups, but ultimately it may well be that rbash, or the -r option is the only way to prevent redirects.

Comment: No, whatever you do with ssh, you would not achieve you goal. It is the local shell which evokes ssh that does the IO redirection.